# Script for creating new spreadsheets with a specific name and data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I spent quite some time looking for a script that will solve my problems but didn't even get close. I was wondering if you've come across a script that can be of use in this situation.

Here is the spreadsheet that I am doing tests with:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nao6q7AbvHl0nlQmBzOWbUgfUY-blhNZ957wI-ozH50/edit#gid=0

- I would like to create copies of this spreadsheet. The number of copies is based on the number of unique values in column A, that is, the emails. In this case, that's 3 emails, so 3 new spreadsheets.
- I would like each new file to be named after a value in column A. So the new files' names are based on the emails.
- I would like each new file to contain only the data corresponding to that email.

Have you come across something that can do this? If can point me in the right direction, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Do you plan to run this script just once or do you need it to run regularly? Will you be updating the source file? If so, does the script need to remember the Spreadsheets it already created and update them or will it be creating a new spreadsheet every time? I can't point you to an algorithm, but I can write one for you, shouldn't take longer than 10 minutes.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]. (besides the lack of details the question also needs more focus)

Comment: VSN I posted my answer. Please have a look at it and let me know if it worked.

Comment: Ruben, the question is closed but my answer solves his problem. So I hope future readers should not be discouraged by the fact that the question is closed.

Comment: @MariosKaramanis In general, avoid answering questions with no code or no reasonable effort. The question is closed to discourage askers from asking low effort questions, where you do the entire work for the OP. In addition, your answer is only code  with no explanations whatsoever. Such code-only answers are highly unlikely to benefit anyone other than OP. What are the chances someone looks for this exact project requirements for free? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bclosed-questions%5D+answers

Comment: @TheMaster I explained each part of the process in a more informative way. Hope that improved my answer. I will avoid answering questions like that in the future. Thanks for your information.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the question can be broken down into three different subtasks:

1. We need to find the unique list of emails. Filter can be used for that purpose:

   ```
   const unique = (value,index,self) =>
   {return self.indexOf(value) ===index;}

   src_emails.filter(unique);
   ```
2. The next step is to create spreadsheet files that are named according to the email address:

   ```
   var crNew = SpreadsheetApp.create(email);
   var target_sh = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(crNew.getUrl());   
   var target_sheet = target_sh.getSheets()[0];
   ```
3. Finally, we need to filter the source data based on the email. We again apply the filter function:

   ```
   var filtered_data = src_sheet_data.filter(function (row) {
   return row[0] === email;
   });
   ```

Here is the complete solution to your question:

```
  function copyEmailData() {
  
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var src_sheet= sh.getSheets()[0];
  
  const unique = (value,index,self) =>
  {return self.indexOf(value) ===index;}
  
  var src_sheet_size = src_sheet.getLastRow();
  var src_emails = src_sheet.getRange("A2:A"+src_sheet_size).getValues().flat([1]);
  var src_u_emails = src_emails.filter(unique);
  var src_sheet_data = src_sheet.getRange("A2:D"+src_sheet_size).getValues();

  src_u_emails.forEach((email)=>{
    
     var filtered_data = src_sheet_data.filter(function (row) {
     return row[0] === email;
     }); 
                       
     var crNew = SpreadsheetApp.create(email);
     var target_sh = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(crNew.getUrl());   
     var target_sheet = target_sh.getSheets()[0];
     target_sheet.appendRow(['Email', 'Name', 'Surname', 'IP'])
     target_sheet.getRange(2,1,filtered_data.length,filtered_data[0].length).setValues(filtered_data)         
    }) 
}
```